# How to I batch comment gerrit reviews?

Tags: bash, gerrit, git-review

I am looking for a CLI solution for adding a comment to a set of gerrit review returned by using its query interface.

Imagine that I have query string like `"project:foobar branch:obsoleted status:open"` and I want to notify all users to abandon their CR and raise them against the new branch.

How can I do this?

A bash or python solution would be desirable, if possible.

Comment: And what is the `bash` string you expect? What kind of output do you want to generate?

Answer (score 0):

The following script adds a comment in every change found using the restriction you've provided:

```
changes=$(curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/changes/?q=project:PROJECT+AND+branch:BRANCH+AND+status:open | sed 1d | jq --raw-output ".[]._number")

for c in $changes
do
    curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://GERRIT-SERVER/changes/$c/revisions/current/review <<EOF
{
    "message": "COMMENT"
}
EOF
done
```